# Game requires higher version of Mac OS X

Tags: mac, games

I have a Mac Pro 1 1, which runs Mac OS X 10.6.8. Recently I installed a game which requires a higher version of Mac OS X. Is there a (free) way to emulate a higher version safely? I have already tried changing systemversion.plist, and using the 'touch' command.

Comment: No as the game will require APIs that are provided by the Apple code in the newer OS X

Comment: There is a way to get a later OS on an early Mac Pro - too long to precis here - http://www.jabbawok.net/?p=47

Comment: What OS X version does the game require? According to http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-quad-2.66-specs.html  your Mac can be updated to 7.5 without any hacking. Just saying since you don't mention which OS X version you require.